# How to make a VGA monitor display a white screen at all time?

Tags: display, vga, crt

I am hacking around with an old (CRT) VGA monitor.

What I want is to make the monitor display a blank white screen at all time, when the power is connected of course. I do not care if I cannot use my monitor for its normal job anymore.

Is it possible to short some pins of the VGA connector to mimic a blank white screen?

Or should I go to http://electronics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Out of curiosity - why?  (I personally have no idea how to do this short of leaving a computer connected SHOWING a solid white screen all the time, so I'll decline answering.)

Comment: You can make an oscilloscope from an old crt, but mine shows a message and automatically shuts of :( and I don't want to keep a computer connected. But I am not familiar with the VGA connector protocol.

Comment: Ooooh, that sounds like fun.  Good luck with that.

Comment: Shorting some pins on the VGA connector won't do what you want.  The VGA interface includes timing signals, e.g. horizontal & vertical sync pulses.  Nothing will be displayed until the monitor can recognize frequency of the pulses.  BTW a white screen will cause the monitor to draw *maximum* electrical power from the AC line.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project for a Raspberry Pi and a HDMI to to VGA adapter...

Comment: Some old VGA monitors displayed white if nothing was connected.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not a monitor technician nor do I work for or am affiliated with the linked company.

The easiest solution (but not the cheapest) is to obtain a VGA monitor tester. They usually have solid color generation functions, and white (as a comment mentioned) is also to test maximum power draw. These can be found ranging from $25 to many hundreds of dollars. For example: http://www.datasynceng.com/vgapdoc.htm

If you want to build your own, it might be less expensive since you only want one function. For that, you'll definitely want to look at the [VGA specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) (see references), [VGA pinout](http://pinouts.ru/Video/VGA15_pinout.shtml), and of course consult the electronics gurus at [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Related or useful:

- SO question: [VGA standard for Graphics Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539784/161052)
- [Building a VGA signal generator](http://www.lucidscience.com/pro-vga%20video%20generator-1.aspx)
- [SoftVGA - AVR based Software-only VGA Display Generator](http://neil.franklin.ch/Projects/SoftVGA/)

Answer (score 1):

All LCD monitors have a white light source behind the panel. You can use this. Forget about delivering a display signal and just figure out what kind of power you need to get just the backlight working.

Tear out all electronics and replace it with a simple power supply that is only connected to that backlight. Done :-)

<sub>yeah I know it's a bit late to answer. Care to tell how it turned out?</sub>